# Получить вчерашнюю дату с помощью Zend_date

Tags: php, дата

Как получить вчерашнюю дату с помощью Zend_date?
Либо полное время 12 часов назад.

Answer (score 1):

Вбиваем в гугле Zend_date, попадаем на сайт [framework.zend.com](http://framework.zend.com/). Чуточку  ходим и попадаем на страницу [Zend_Date API Overview](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.date.overview.html). Там видим использование метода add.  Чуточку думаем и узнаем, что есть метод [sub](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.date.constants.html#zend.date.constants.list), где прямо в примере показано как взять дату 12 часов назад.